# how to decorate a function with decorators when a argument is passed or say a condition is matched

Tags: python, python-decorators

**This is the simple decorators with arguments:**

***app.py***

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time

def newdecorator(arg1):
    def benchmarking(funct):
        #The argument is accessible here
        print("this is the value of argument",arg1)
        def timercheck(*args, **kwarg):
            starttime=time.time()
            print("starting time",time.time())
            funct(*args, **kwarg)
            print("TOTAL TIME TAKEN ::",time.time()-starttime)
        return timercheck
    return benchmarking

#passing value to the decorators with arguments
@newdecorator('arg value')
def tara():
    print("hellow testing")

if __name__=="__main__":
    tara()
```

The decorators are working well. It decorates the function with a functionality to show the starting time an the time taken by it.

**What I want to achieve:**
I want the decorators to be conditionally implemented I mean.

- > when a user runs app.py let the decorators not be implemented
- > user runs app.py -t than want the decorators to be implemented

I will be using the argparse module for the argument parsing that is not a big problem what I am wondering is how to make the decorators work conditionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use a global variable in the module or some other namespace, but that might only be useful if you want to use this state for something else as well. It's not uncommon to have application settings that configure decorator behaviour.

```
import time

TIMING_ENABLED = True


def newdecorator():
    def benchmarking(funct):
        def timercheck(*args, **kwarg):
            if TIMING_ENABLED:
                starttime = time.time()
                print("starting time", time.time())
            funct(*args, **kwarg)
            if TIMING_ENABLED:
                print("TOTAL TIME TAKEN ::", time.time() - starttime)
        return timercheck
    return benchmarking

# passing value to the decorators with arguments


@newdecorator()
def tara():
    print("hellow testing")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TIMING_ENABLED = False
    tara()
```

It's important to put the conditional checks inside the `timercheck` function because the lower scopes are executed during the module initialisation (before `main()` is executed) and we will not get the chance to set the `TIMING_ENABLED` variable.

If you only want this to be an on/off thing, then @Rawing's answer is the way to go.

Since you don't need any parameters to this specific decorator you can also simplify it. We apply the decorator without `()` and can drop one level of nesting. In addition we add the `functools.wraps` decorator to `timecheck` so this function will look like the `tara` function to python. (See additional prints in `main`) since what the decorator does is actually replacing the `tara` function with `timecheck`.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time
from functools import wraps

TIMING_ENABLED = True

def newdecorator(funct):
    @wraps(funct)
    def timercheck(*args, **kwarg):
        if TIMING_ENABLED:
            starttime=time.time()
            print("starting time",time.time())
        funct(*args, **kwarg)
        if TIMING_ENABLED:
            print("TOTAL TIME TAKEN ::",time.time()-starttime)
    return timercheck

@newdecorator
def tara():
    """Docs for tara function"""
    print("hellow testing")

if __name__=="__main__":
    TIMING_ENABLED = True
    print(tara.__name__, tara.__doc__)
    tara()
```

You can always remove the `@wraps(funct)` line and see what `main` will print out differently about the `tara` function.

Answer (score 1):

The `@decorator` syntax is just syntactic sugar. Under the hood, all that happens is that the decorator is called with the decorated function as its argument.

So you can just define your function without a decorator and then apply the decorator if a condition is met:

```
def tara():
    print("hellow testing")

if script_called_with_t_flag:
    tara = newdecorator('arg value')(tara)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use sys module to run Python script using arguments in windows command line

Run this code in terminal with **python app.py True** to enable decorator and for disable decorator **python app.py** or **python app.py False**

```
import time
import sys

TIMING_ENABLED = True


def newdecorator():
    def benchmarking(funct):
        def timercheck(*args, **kwarg):
            if TIMING_ENABLED:
                starttime = time.time()
                print("starting time", time.time())
            funct(*args, **kwarg)
            if TIMING_ENABLED:
                print("TOTAL TIME TAKEN ::", time.time()-starttime)
        return timercheck
    return benchmarking

# passing value to the decorators with arguments


@newdecorator()
def tara():
    print("hellow testing")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TIMING_ENABLED = sys.argv[1]
    tara()
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to conditionally apply the decorator only if the script was called with `-t` and otherwise do nothing:

```
import time

script_called_with_t = True

def newdecorator(arg1):
    if script_called_with_t:
        def benchmarking(funct):
            #The argument is accessible here
            print("this is the value of argument",arg1)
            def timercheck(*args, **kwarg):
                starttime=time.time()
                print("starting time",time.time())
                funct(*args, **kwarg)
                print("TOTAL TIME TAKEN ::",time.time()-starttime)
            return timercheck
        return benchmarking
    else:
        return lambda funct: funct

#passing value to the decorators with arguments
@newdecorator('arg value')
def tara():
    print("hellow testing")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TIMING_ENABLED = False
    tara()
```